# Mmedia integration problems

Tags: java, android, integration, ads

I've been emailing back and forth with their tech support for over a week and they can't seem to figure out whats going on...

im a new developer so im making a really simple app to walk myself through the basics including integrating an ad company (i chose mmedia)

THE PROBLEM IS:

Through their site, i can see the ad requests are being sent and received and this was confirmed by the company, BUT when you open the app itself you see a space where the banner should be displaying the ads its calling but nothing ever happens

ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED

Logcat error "unhandled event loop exception"

```
03-12 19:31:23.361: D/dalvikvm(266): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/lib/libnmsp_speex.so 0x45f3dc30
03-12 19:31:23.373: D/dalvikvm(266): Added shared lib /data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/lib/libnmsp_speex.so 0x45f3dc30
03-12 19:31:23.391: D/dalvikvm(266): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/lib/libnmsp_speex.so 0x45f3dc30, skipping init
03-12 19:31:24.352: I/MillennialMediaSDK(266): Initializing MMLayout.
03-12 19:31:25.043: D/dalvikvm(266): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5029 objects / 300200 bytes in 158ms
03-12 19:31:25.822: W/MillennialMediaSDK(266): MMLayout adding view (MMWebView originally from(1) MRaidState(loading).com.millennialmedia.android.MMWebView@45fa9950) to AdType[(b) InternalId(1) LinkedId(0) isFinishing(false)]
03-12 19:31:25.852: I/MillennialMediaSDK(266): Initializing MMLayout.
03-12 19:31:26.042: D/dalvikvm(266): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5307 objects / 266960 bytes in 181ms
03-12 19:31:26.201: I/MillennialMediaSDK(266): A request is already in progress.
03-12 19:31:26.412: W/MillennialMediaSDK(266): MMLayout adding view (MMWebView originally from(2) MRaidState(loading).com.millennialmedia.android.MMWebView@45f36248) to AdType[(b) InternalId(2) LinkedId(0) isFinishing(false)]
03-12 19:31:28.511: D/dalvikvm(266): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4020 objects / 397408 bytes in 727ms
03-12 19:31:28.521: W/MillennialMediaSDK(266):  @@@ SENDING IT!!!@@@@@  adSize ! {"height":0,"width":0,"x":0,"y":50}
03-12 19:31:28.571: W/MillennialMediaSDK(266): Id check for parent: 2 versus 2
03-12 19:31:29.062: E/Web Console(266): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
03-12 19:31:29.062: E/Web Console(266): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
03-12 19:31:29.672: D/dalvikvm(266): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4494 objects / 277928 bytes in 162ms
03-12 19:31:29.942: D/dalvikvm(266): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1276 objects / 75352 bytes in 149ms
03-12 19:31:29.972: W/System.err(266): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-12 19:31:29.982: W/System.err(266):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
03-12 19:31:30.052: W/System.err(266):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:93)
03-12 19:31:30.052: W/System.err(266):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
03-12 19:31:30.052: W/System.err(266):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
03-12 19:31:30.052: W/System.err(266):  at com.millennialmedia.android.HandShake.parseJson(HandShake.java:615)
03-12 19:31:30.052: W/System.err(266):  at com.millennialmedia.android.HandShake.access$400(HandShake.java:39)
03-12 19:31:30.052: W/System.err(266):  at com.millennialmedia.android.HandShake$1.run(HandShake.java:337)
03-12 19:31:30.062: W/System.err(266):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-12 19:31:30.071: W/System.err(266):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-12 19:31:30.071: W/System.err(266):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-12 19:31:30.391: W/MillennialMediaSDK(266): MMJS - same URL
03-12 19:31:30.391: W/MillennialMediaSDK(266): Not downloading MMJS - (http://cdn.millennialmedia.com/mmjs/v1.4/mm.js)
03-12 19:31:31.932: E/Web Console(266): TypeError: Result of expression 'window.interface' [undefined] is not an object. at http://ads.mp.mydas.mobi/:1
03-12 19:31:31.992: W/webcore(266): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
03-12 19:31:32.212: D/dalvikvm(266): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4874 objects / 440896 bytes in 83ms
03-12 19:31:32.231: D/NativeCrypto(266): Freeing OpenSSL session
03-12 19:31:32.281: I/Web Console(266): setAdProperties: {"permissions":{"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION":true},"device":{"platform":"Android","connection":"umts","mmisdk":"5.1.0-13.08.12.a","height":854,"density":1.5,"mmdid":"mmh_CF95DC53F383F9A836FD749F3EF439CD_41E29575C7361B2924F701502CA6D932B45B9E51","width":480,"device":"sdk","language":"en","cookies":[{"path":"/","name":"MAC-ID"}],"country":"US","version":"2.2","sdkVersion":"5.1.0-13.08.12.a"},"ad":{"width":"0","height":"0"},"screen":{"width":"320","height":"569"},"supports":{"inlineVideo":"true","sms":"false","storePicture":"false","calendar":"false","tel":"false"},"do":"portrait","maxSize":{"width":"320","height":"569"}} at file:///data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/files/.mmsyscache/mraid.js:221
03-12 19:31:32.361: I/Web Console(266): MRAID state change from "loading" to "default" at file:///data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/files/.mmsyscache/mraid.js:221
03-12 19:31:32.381: I/Web Console(266): event callback: stateChange at file:///data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/files/.mmsyscache/mraid.js:221
03-12 19:31:32.391: I/Web Console(266): MRAID ready. at file:///data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/files/.mmsyscache/mraid.js:221
03-12 19:31:32.391: I/Web Console(266): event callback: ready at file:///data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/files/.mmsyscache/mraid.js:221
03-12 19:31:47.011: D/dalvikvm(320): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/lib/libnmsp_speex.so 0x45f3dbd8
03-12 19:31:47.021: D/dalvikvm(320): Added shared lib /data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/lib/libnmsp_speex.so 0x45f3dbd8
03-12 19:31:47.021: D/dalvikvm(320): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/lib/libnmsp_speex.so 0x45f3dbd8, skipping init
03-12 19:31:47.332: I/MillennialMediaSDK(320): Initializing MMLayout.
03-12 19:31:47.542: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4275 objects / 268528 bytes in 84ms
03-12 19:31:48.022: W/MillennialMediaSDK(320): MMLayout adding view (MMWebView originally from(1) MRaidState(loading).com.millennialmedia.android.MMWebView@45f8d4e0) to AdType[(b) InternalId(1) LinkedId(0) isFinishing(false)]
03-12 19:31:48.091: I/MillennialMediaSDK(320): Initializing MMLayout.
03-12 19:31:48.172: I/MillennialMediaSDK(320): A request is already in progress.
03-12 19:31:48.332: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5133 objects / 259400 bytes in 117ms
03-12 19:31:48.841: W/MillennialMediaSDK(320): MMLayout adding view (MMWebView originally from(2) MRaidState(loading).com.millennialmedia.android.MMWebView@45f36130) to AdType[(b) InternalId(2) LinkedId(0) isFinishing(false)]
03-12 19:31:50.022: W/MillennialMediaSDK(320):  @@@ SENDING IT!!!@@@@@  adSize ! {"height":0,"width":0,"x":0,"y":480}
03-12 19:31:50.052: W/MillennialMediaSDK(320): Id check for parent: 2 versus 2
03-12 19:31:50.302: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5527 objects / 499848 bytes in 73ms
03-12 19:31:50.352: E/Web Console(320): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
03-12 19:31:50.352: E/Web Console(320): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
03-12 19:31:50.691: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 472 objects / 28000 bytes in 329ms
03-12 19:31:50.962: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1379 objects / 74616 bytes in 88ms
03-12 19:31:50.962: I/dalvikvm-heap(320): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.336MB for 87396-byte allocation
03-12 19:31:51.063: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 234 objects / 16808 bytes in 103ms
03-12 19:31:51.142: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 989 objects / 45056 bytes in 72ms
03-12 19:31:51.352: W/MillennialMediaSDK(320): MMJS - same URL
03-12 19:31:51.352: W/MillennialMediaSDK(320): Not downloading MMJS - (http://cdn.millennialmedia.com/mmjs/v1.4/mm.js)
03-12 19:31:51.531: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3914 objects / 248624 bytes in 70ms
03-12 19:31:52.062: E/Web Console(320): TypeError: Result of expression 'window.interface' [undefined] is not an object. at http://ads.mp.mydas.mobi/:1
03-12 19:31:52.082: W/webcore(320): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
03-12 19:31:52.222: I/Web Console(320): setAdProperties: {"permissions":{"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION":true},"device":{"platform":"Android","connection":"umts","mmisdk":"5.1.0-13.08.12.a","height":854,"density":1.5,"mmdid":"mmh_CF95DC53F383F9A836FD749F3EF439CD_41E29575C7361B2924F701502CA6D932B45B9E51","width":480,"device":"sdk","language":"en","cookies":[{"path":"/","name":"MAC-ID"}],"country":"US","version":"2.2","sdkVersion":"5.1.0-13.08.12.a"},"ad":{"width":"0","height":"0"},"screen":{"width":"320","height":"569"},"supports":{"inlineVideo":"true","sms":"false","storePicture":"false","calendar":"false","tel":"false"},"do":"portrait","maxSize":{"width":"320","height":"569"}} at file:///data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/files/.mmsyscache/mraid.js:221
03-12 19:31:52.242: I/Web Console(320): MRAID state change from "loading" to "default" at file:///data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/files/.mmsyscache/mraid.js:221
03-12 19:31:52.242: I/Web Console(320): event callback: stateChange at file:///data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/files/.mmsyscache/mraid.js:221
03-12 19:31:52.252: I/Web Console(320): MRAID ready. at file:///data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/files/.mmsyscache/mraid.js:221
03-12 19:31:52.252: I/Web Console(320): event callback: ready at file:///data/data/com.loudest.airhornextreme/files/.mmsyscache/mraid.js:221
03-12 19:33:10.521: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 15996 objects / 732152 bytes in 81ms
03-12 19:35:08.252: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 21998 objects / 717432 bytes in 77ms
03-12 19:37:06.082: D/dalvikvm(320): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 21763
```

objects / 524272 bytes in 70ms

and for my code,

**Manifest:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.loudest.airhornextreme"
        android:versionCode="102"
        android:versionName="1.2" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="Air Horn Extreme"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <activity
                android:name=".Splash"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_airhornextreme" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.loudest.airhornextreme.Soundboard"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_airhornextreme" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.loudest.airhornextreme.STARTINGPOINT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
            </activity>
            <service
                android:name="com.loudest.airhornextreme.LocationObject"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true" >
            </service>
        </application>

    </manifest>

**Layout**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mm="http://millennialmedia.com/android/schema"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.loudest.airhornextreme"   
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sound1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="CLEAN HORN" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sound3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="ECHO HORN" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sound2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="HIGH HORN" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sound4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="LOUDEST HORN" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sound5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="LOW HORN" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sound6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="REVERB HORN" >
    </Button>




    <com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        mm:apid="153971"
        mm:height="match_parent"
        mm:width="match_parent" />


</TableLayout>


        **MAIN JAVA**

    package com.loudest.airhornextreme;

    import com.loudest.airhornextreme.R;

    import com.loudest.airhornextreme.SoundManager;
    import com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView;
    import com.millennialmedia.android.MMRequest;
    import com.millennialmedia.android.MMSDK;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


    public class Soundboard extends Activity {



        private SoundManager mSoundManager;

        protected boolean canFit(int adWidth) {
            int adWidthPx = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, adWidth, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            return metrics.widthPixels >= adWidthPx;
        }

      //Constants for tablet sized ads (728x90)
        private static final int IAB_LEADERBOARD_WIDTH = 728;
        private static final int IAB_LEADERBOARD_HEIGHT = 90;

        private static final int MED_BANNER_WIDTH = 480;
        private static final int MED_BANNER_HEIGHT = 60;

        //Constants for phone sized ads (320x50)
        private static final int BANNER_AD_WIDTH = 320;
        private static final int BANNER_AD_HEIGHT = 50;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



                {

                    MMSDK.initialize(this);
                }

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_soundboardtest);

                MMAdView adView = (MMAdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

                //Replace YOUR_APID with the APID provided to you by Millennial Media
                adView.setApid("153971");

                //Set your metadata in the MMRequest object
                MMRequest request = new MMRequest();

                //Add metadata here.

                //Add the MMRequest object to your MMAdView.
                adView.setMMRequest(request);

                //Sets the id to preserve your ad on configuration changes.
                adView.setId(MMSDK.getDefaultAdId());
                adView.getAd();

                int placementWidth = BANNER_AD_WIDTH;
                int placementHeight = BANNER_AD_HEIGHT;

                //Finds an ad that best fits a users device.
                if(canFit(IAB_LEADERBOARD_WIDTH)) {
                    placementWidth = IAB_LEADERBOARD_WIDTH;
                    placementHeight = IAB_LEADERBOARD_HEIGHT;
                } else if(canFit(MED_BANNER_WIDTH)) {
                    placementWidth = MED_BANNER_WIDTH;
                    placementHeight = MED_BANNER_HEIGHT;
                }

            //screenwake

            getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_soundboardtest);

          //Set the ad size. Replace the width and height values if needed.
            adView.setWidth(placementWidth);
            adView.setHeight(placementHeight);

            //Calculate the size of the adView based on the ad size. Replace the width and height values if needed.
            int layoutWidth = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, placementWidth, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int layoutHeight = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, placementHeight, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            //Create the layout parameters using the calculated adView width and height.
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(layoutWidth, layoutHeight);

            //This positions the banner.
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            adView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


            adView.getAd();

            mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
            mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
            mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.sound1);
            mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.sound2);
            mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.sound3);
            mSoundManager.addSound(4, R.raw.sound4);
            mSoundManager.addSound(5, R.raw.sound5);
            mSoundManager.addSound(6, R.raw.sound6);


            Button SoundButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound1);
            SoundButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(1);

        }
    });       
            Button SoundButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound2);
            SoundButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(2);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound3);
            SoundButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(3);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound4);
            SoundButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(4);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound5);
            SoundButton5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(5);

        }
    });   
            Button SoundButton6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound6);
            SoundButton6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(6);

        }
    });    



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is you have this appearing twice in your code:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_soundboardtest);
```

It should only be at the very beginning of your Activity's onCreate(...) method. The thing that gave it away was in your logcat:

```
        03-12 19:31:26.201: I/MillennialMediaSDK(266): A request is already in progress.
```

I've pasted your code into an Eclipse project, removed the second instance of the above two lines and gotten everything to show correctly. What's happening is this: The main activity is being created with the MMAdView, then it's wiping away the old instance of the MMAdView, creating a new one (which fails due to the asynchronous nature of advertising SDKs in general), and adding the sound buttons to the new layout.

Update the ticket you've already put in to us if there's anything we're missing here!